# FeathersJS + Knex: Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, knex.js, feathersjs

I used the default FeathersJS generator to boilerplate an api and create a service.
I am trying to rewrite the `create` method in the service. At defining the method I get the following TS error:

```
Property 'create' in type 'UserService<ServiceParams>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'KnexService<{ email: string; password: string; id: string; }, { email: string; password: string; }, KnexAdapterParams<AdapterQuery>, Partial<{ email: string; password: string; }>>'.
  Type '(data: { email: string; password: string; }, params?: KnexAdapterParams<AdapterQuery> | undefined) => Promise<{ email: string; password: string; id: string; }>' is not assignable to type '{ (data: { email: string; password: string; }, params?: KnexAdapterParams<AdapterQuery> | undefined): Promise<{ email: string; password: string; id: string; }>; (data: { ...; }[], params?: KnexAdapterParams<...> | undefined): Promise<...>; (data: { ...; } | { ...; }[], params?: KnexAdapterParams<...> | undefined): P...'.
    Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
      Type '{ email: string; password: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ email: string; password: string; }': email, password ts(2416)
```

My types are defined with `zod`:

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const createUserSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string(),
  password: z.string(),
})

const userSchema = createUserSchema.extend({
  id: z.string(),
})

type User = z.infer<typeof userSchema>
type CreateUser = z.infer<typeof createUserSchema>

export { CreateUser, User, userSchema }
```

And my service looks like this:

```
import type { Params } from '@feathersjs/feathers'
import type { KnexAdapterOptions, KnexAdapterParams } from '@feathersjs/knex'
import { KnexService } from '@feathersjs/knex'

import { AdapterQuery } from '@feathersjs/adapter-commons'
import type { Application } from '../../declarations'
import { CreateUser, User } from '../../models/users.model'

type UserQuery = any

export type { UserQuery }

export interface UserParams extends KnexAdapterParams<UserQuery> { }

// By default calls the standard Knex adapter service methods but can be customized with your own functionality.
export class UserService<ServiceParams extends Params = UserParams> extends KnexService<
  User,
  CreateUser
> {
  create(data: CreateUser, params?: KnexAdapterParams<AdapterQuery> | undefined): Promise<User> {
    return super.create(data, params)
  }
}

export const getOptions = (app: Application): KnexAdapterOptions => {
  return {
    paginate: app.get('paginate'),
    Model: app.get('postgresqlClient'),
    name: 'users'
  }
}
```

In the IDE I see also the following error description:

```
Types of parameters data and data are incompatible. Type { email: string; password: string; }[] is missing the following properties from type { email: string; password: string; }: email, password
```

If I understand it correctly, the problem is, that `data` is expected to be an array.

**What causes the issue, and how can I resolve it?**

What I tried:

- I was going with the official documentation and tutorial, extensive examples are written for/in TypeBox or jsonSchema
- I tried to implement my logic according to the documentation.
- I tried to find similar questions/answers, without luck

Relevant packages:

- "@feathersjs/feathers": "^5.0.24",
- "@feathersjs/knex": "^5.0.24",